# Integrating matplotlib (Python) with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio, matplotlib

I would like to know if it's possible to run some Python script containing  matplotlib graphs (e.g 3D surfaces) on Android Studio.

If no, what could be another way I can do that?

Comment: Are you asking if you can run an app written in python on Android?  Not without a lot of conversion for the UI part of the code, to the point it will be easier to rewrite it.  Or are you asking if you can run it and dump output files in a build?

Comment: @GabeSechan Both. I would like to know what are the possibilities. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if you can run Python script inside the Android Studio, however you can create a Python API which listens on a specific endpoint and make a POST request to that API endpoint from code inside Android Studio. If you want to know how to create a service using Python, you can have a look at  [this link](https://medium.com/@ssola/building-microservices-with-python-part-i-5240a8dcc2fb). You can also create an API using [Flask](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/flask-tutorial/)/[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/overview/) and deploy it as a service by making a systemd unit file (like it is mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7) for CentOS).

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll take a look at this. Thanks for answering.